# Rails 3.1 Rspec Association Through Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec, model-associations

I've successfully tested the association between a brand (has_many :products) and a product (belongs_to :brand). Now I'm curious to see if I could test in Rspec the association between a user (has_many :brands, has_many products, :through => :brands) and his brand's products. The code below is something I kind of had in mind, but obviously it does not work.

```
describe "user association" do
before(:each) do
  @brand_attr = { :name => "Apple", 
                  :established => "1976", 
                  :description => "Born at the SV Homebrew"
                }
  @user = Factory(:user)
  @brand = @user.brands.new(@brand_attr)
  @product = @brand.products.new(@attr)
end

it "should have a user attribute through the brand" do
  @product.brand.user.should == @user
end
```

Thank you!